# What is the difference between member: str = 'test' and member = 'test' in a subclass of typing.NamedTuple?

Tags: python-3.x, namedtuple

```py
from typing import NamedTuple

class TestClass1(NamedTuple):
    member1: str = 'test1'

class TestClass2(NamedTuple):
    member2 = 'test2'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(TestClass1.member1)
    print(TestClass2.member2)
```

Output:

> <_collections._tuplegetter object at 0x117e20c10>

> test2

Comment: `TestClass1` defines a tuple with one element that is a string, `member1`. `TestClass2` defines a tuple with no elements, `member2` is just a class attribute.

Answer (score 0):

```
member1: str = 'test1'
```

It is a syntax sugar for create a named tuple class, it doesn't mean member1 is a class variable of TestClass1.

if you want to print 'test1', you should create an object by TestClass1:

```
test = TestClass1() //accept one para for member1, default is 'test1'
print(test.member1)
```